# Error in std::getline function (fstreeam _Lock())

Tags: c++, file, locking, getline

I keep getting an error when call std::getline, the debugger shows a break in a fstream function """virtual void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Lock()"""

Here is my code (Read File function):

```
string GetFile(const string& fileName)
{
    string line;
    string output;
    ifstream myfile (fileName);
    myfile.open(fileName);//.c_str());

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            //cout << line << '\n';
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }
        myfile.close();

    } else cout << "Unable to open file";

    return output;
}
```

(ADDED)
the break message:

Unhandled exception at 0x7787FC47 (ntdll.dll) in Engine.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

and the break in fstream shows this function:

```
virtual void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Lock()
    {   // lock file instead of stream buffer
    if (_Myfile)
        _CSTD _lock_file(_Myfile);
    }
```

I Have no idea what is the problem

Comment: And if you go up the function call stack, it's in the `getline` call it happens?

Comment: @joachim-pileborg yes, the error is calling getline function, I put a getchar() before , and nothing happen, then after the getline and gives me the error

Comment: `is_open()` does not check for error conditions. Try `if (myfile)` instead. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Comment: @captain-giraffe Still getting the error, but this time prints "Unable to open file"

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer but it's a start. I've made a new project and use this code (the same that always):

```
#define Dir "C:\\difuseVS.txt"

using namespace std;

string GetFile(const string& fileName)
{

string line;
string output;
ifstream myfile(fileName);


if (myfile)
 {

     while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      //cout << line << '\n';
      output.append(line + "\n");
    }
 myfile.close();

}else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

return output;
}

int main()
{
cout << GetFile(Dir);
getchar();

}
```

And it works perfectly!! the problem is in the project configuration, but I don't know where exactly

Comment: Any idea why the code runs fine in a new project and doesn't in my original project?? the configuration of both is the same

Answer (score 0):

Trapped by same problem, I found this link give me some clue.
http://www.heapoverflow.me/question-fstream-included-but-ifstream-not-found-and-identifier-is-undefined-26761708

For my env(vs2010), I just added msvcrtd.lib to my Project Property->Linker->Input->additional dependencies and the headache gone, as my Runtime Library is Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) already, if not then probably need to set it as well

Answer (score 0):

The constructor:

```
ifstream myfile (fileName);
```

opens the file. Then:

```
myfile.open(fileName);
```

should fail; see [ifstream::open - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/) that says "If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function fails". Of course, it seems that "myfile.is_open()" should return FALSE. Since this is an old question I assume it is not worth pursuing further but perhaps this will help someone in the future in the unlikely event that the same problem is encountered.